# Multiple rows being updated via checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, sql-update

I've got a query which selects a list of the un-returned loans from my loan table, and so I'm trying to make a checkbox for each row of which when selected the value for the "returned" field is set to "1" (true), upon the click of a submit button, the rows selected should then be updated to "1"... for some reason my query doesnt seem to show all the unreturned books although when I echo the count, the correct number is shown :S Here is the code I have so far (Thanks for any help in advance!)

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Loan ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Username</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Book ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Return Date</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox"         id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['loan_id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['loan_id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['book_id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['return_date']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="update" type="submit"         id="update" value="UPDATE LOANS"></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this
if($update){
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
 $update_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET returned = "1" WHERE loan_id='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=test_checkbox.php\">";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>

</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @njk Oh right, didnt know that, anyway you could help me though?

Answer (score 0):

This code will get you started with converting to `mysqli_`. It will only retrieve your record set.

```
<?php

  $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "my_db");

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  $query = "SELECT loan_id, username, book_id, return_date FROM '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $tbl_name) . "'";
  //echo "login log query is $query <br />\n";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

  if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Loan ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Username</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Book ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Return Date</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    /* fetch associative array */
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row['loan_id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $row['loan_id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $row['username']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $row['book_id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $row['return_date']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="UPDATE LOANS"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
  }

  /* close connection */
  mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Oh okay, cool thanks! Just before you answered, I'd just got it to show the result of the query, now I'm having trouble with actually getting the UPDATE to work.